# Why isn't this javascript running

Tags: javascript

I dont understand, but all that shows is the HTML "end", none of the javascript is being run.  Why?  The browser is chrome and is set to allow javascript.  Doing javascript:alert('hello') in the address bar works!

```
<html>
<title>
Javascript test
</title>
<head>
<body>
<script
type="text/javascript">
    document.write('Hello!');
    var = prompt("What is your name?");
    alert("Hello, " var);
</script>
<h1>End</h1>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the error console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in these lines:

```
//Missing variable name
var = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello, " var);
```

Try:

```
var x = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello, " + x);
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot var was for declaring variables, I didn't remember it was reserved.  That was it!  I will accept this answer when I am able.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = prompt("What is your name?");
```

you have not declare the variable

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello, " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the variable name:

```
var res = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello, " res);
```